# Get the alpha of an ImageView

Tags: android

How can I do this? There's a setAlpha but no getAlpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this.  This is because an `ImageView` might have been set with a `Bitmap`, a `StateListDrawable`, a `ColorDrawable`, or something else entirely.  Only one of those classes has a single color; on any other drawable the alpha might be different for each pixel (pixels are in ARGB format, w/ 1 byte each for alpha, red, green, and blue).  I'm pretty sure the `setAlpha()` method only works on drawables that support it, as mentioned by Sephy above.

What exactly do you need to know about the image's transparency?  If you know what the ImageView will be filled with ahead of time, then perhaps you can extract the alpha beforehand.  If you don't have direct access to the alpha, but you are able to determine the color, then the alpha will be equal to `color >>> 24`.

Comment: I'm animating some ImageViews using an AlphaAnimation and I want to check if their alpha is 1 to determine if I should run my fadeIn animation on them.

Comment: Is this just to know the difference between which views were already animated and which views weren't?  You should probably come up with some other way of figuring that out, for example if `imgView.getAnimation() != fadeIn` then you assume that the animation has yet to be applied.  Alternatively, you could subclass `ImageView` and override the `onSetAlpha()` method; that's the method that will be called when alpha changes due to animation.

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go `View.ALPHA.get(View)`

You can use this with an if statement to get a Boolean value and check for the current alpha state of a view.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone just need get and set a controls visibility, getVisibility and setVisibility may be an alternative you can use:

```
if(vw.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
{
    // do something
}
```

and you can set the visibility:

```
vw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to use [`getOpacity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getOpacity%28%29) because get alpha existe only for `ColorDrawable`, `Transformation` and a few others. and you need to use it on the drawable of the `ImageView` not the view itself.

Comment: Hmm. getDrawable() is null if I set the ImageView src through XML instead of through setImageResource at run time. Any ideas?

Comment: Woops, I was setting background instead of src. getOpacity doesn't do anything useful though, it just returns one of 4 constants, I need something which returns the actual transparency value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly. You can workaround, provided you're setting the alpha programmatically, is to keep the alpha value when you set it. E.g.:

```
private int mCurrentAlpha;

private void setAlpha(int newAlpha){
   mCurrentAlpha=newAlpha;
   ImageView imageView=...
   imageView.setAlpha(mCurrentAlpha);
}
```